# Can this code be simplified?

Tags: c#

This piece of code is a lot `if/else` and I want to know if it can be simplified to a handful of lines. The code works perfectly fine, but I prefer to have a more efficient and cleaner way.

```
if (textBox_naam.Text.Length < 3)
{
   textBox_naam.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(205, 92, 92);
}
else
{
   textBox_naam.BackColor = Color.White;
}

if (textBox_email.Text.Length < 5)
{
   textBox_email.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(205, 92, 92);
}
else
{
   textBox_email.BackColor = Color.White;
}

if (textBox_body.Text.Length < 20)
{
   textBox_body.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(205, 92, 92);
}
else
{
   textBox_body.BackColor = Color.White;
}
```

Comment: We have a sister site for code review of working code.

Comment: Just to clarify, it seems you are referring to different TextBox's in your code?  I was almost going to collapse the branch statements into one if...else if...  But I think @Daren's answer helps?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your easiest bet (no tricks involved!) would be:

```
SetBackColor(textBox_naam, 3, GOOD_COLOR, BAD_COLOR);
SetBackColor(textBox_email, 5, GOOD_COLOR, BAD_COLOR);
SetBackColor(textBox_body, 20, GOOD_COLOR, BAD_COLOR);
```

with a method `SetBackColor` defined like this:

```
public void SetBackColor(TextBox tb, int minLength, Color goodColor, Color badColor)
{
    tb.BackColor = tb.Text.Length < minLength ? badColor : goodColor;
}
```

Comment: Given that the "GOOD_COLOR" and "BAD_COLOR" are the same in all three cases, there's not much reason to make them be parameters to the function. Just pass in the field and length, and let them be constants within the function.

Comment: I am not picky. But shouldn't it be `tb.Text.Length < minLength` instead of `tb.Text < minLength`?

Comment: Thanks, will be using methods then! :-)

Comment: @Arion, you are of course right. Looks like someone came and edited it for me. Thanks @kaj!

Comment: I guess one could get creative and make this a static extension method (for syntactic sugar off course), so someone can write: textBox_naam.SetBackColor(3, GOOD_COLOR, BAD_COLOR);.  The only concern is to find a way of encouraging the compiler to inline this code to reduce Stack overhead. Or what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ternary if then else operator

```
textBox_naam.BackColor = textBox_naam.Text.Length < 3 ? Color.FromArgb(205, 92, 92) : Color.White;
```

This isn't any more efficient, but will use less lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could use shorthand if statements...

```
Color other=Color.FromArgb(205,92,92);
textBox_naam.BackColor=(textBox_naam.Text.Length<3?other:Color.White);
textBox_email.BackColor=(textBox_email.Text.Length<5?other:Color.White);
textBox_body.BackColor=(textBox_body.Text.Length<20?other:Color.White);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have **Reshaper** installed? I think you will find a great (future) assistance by using JetBrain's **Reshaper** extension for VS. Depend on it, it is  great *must-have* tool for .NET developers.

Comment: Do you mind sharing how the extension can be used in this scenario?